# Check if changes was made on repository for scheduled Jenkins job

Tags: jenkins-pipeline, gerrit, gerrit-trigger

I got scheduled Jenkins job with numerous stages integrated with gerrit.
I want to check on the first phase if any changes was made on repository (new code, auto-bumps,etc...)
On scheduled jobs I have no GERRIT_OLDREV and GERRIT_NEWREV variables.

How can I do that?

Thanks

Comment: `if any changes was made on repository` as compared to what exactly?

Comment: Be more specific what you would like to check. I use the API to check for new patchsets to the same change, if a new patchset is detected the current build will be abandoned.